# ошибка типизации при создании npm пакета

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsconfig

писал свой npm пакет на `TypeScript`
если описать интерфейсы и типы внутри главного файла, то все нормально

```typescript
    interface IProps {
      title: string;
      text: string;
    }

    function myFn (prop: IProps ) {...}
```

но если использовать импорты

```typescript
    import { IProps } from "./interfaces.ts"

    function myFn (prop: IProps ) {...}
```

то при публикации и скачивании пакета, в файле `ts` при импорте элемента из пакета вылезает ошибка "`index.d.ts` не является модулем." или "не удается найти модуль ХХХ или связанные с ним объявления типов."

может кто то объяснить почему так и можно ли настроить компиляцию при вызове `tsc`, чтобы все работало в любом случае?

если у кого то есть собственный `tsconfig.json` файл, который часто используется и решает эту проблему (все импортированные типы вписываются в скомпилированные файлы и не вызывают ошибок), то был бы рад, если поделитесь

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package

Comment: @user7860670 прикол в том, что я это все читал и делал, у меня было всего 2 файла index.js и index.d.ts, в package.json указал как в доке, и все равно ошибка